# Encrypt files before putting into Dropbox using Python

Tags: python, encryption, dropbox

I want to encrypt files before uploading into Dropbox using keys and some encryption standards in Python. How would I do that in code without using any third party tools?

Comment: without using any third party tools? It's going to be hard (as in impossible). If you're worried about verifying the security of the solution, you'd be better served by looking for open-source tools.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a cryptographic library like [pycrypto](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto/2.6). Cryptography is hard, and doing it yourself is a sure way to have security holes.

Oh, and you should read this article by Bruce Schneier: [Why cryptography is hard](http://www.schneier.com/essay-037.html).

Comment: +1 for indicating security holes. If you don't know enough about security topics, all your efforts will somehow be destined to be poor.

Comment: The problem is that even with libraries, crypto is easy to get wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using [pyDes](http://twhiteman.netfirms.com/des.html) and/or [rsa](http://stuvel.eu/rsa)

Comment: DES is very weak. 3DES is slow and the small block size is annoying. Use AES instead. I don't really see how RSA fits the OPs problem either.